# One to Many with Circular Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to build a structure that has many domains and menus.
All Menus are related to a domain with DomainID, So each domain can manage owns.

Also, domain owners can select where to show to menu, it may be on Heade or on Footer areas.

Here is my models

```
public class Domain
    {
        [Key]
        public int DomainID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Template { get; set; }
        public string BookingType { get; set; }

        public int? HeaderMenuID { get; set; }
        public int? FooterMenuID { get; set; }

        public virtual Menu HeaderMenu {get;set;}
        public virtual Menu FooterMenu { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DomainTranslation> DomainTranslations { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Form> Forms { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    }



public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public int DomainID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentMenuID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentMenuID")]
    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }


    public virtual List<MenuTranslation> MenuTranslations { get; set; }
    public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
}
```

When I update-database expected fileds on Menu database is :

```
[MenuID]
[DomainID]
[ParentMenuID]
```

But it is populating as

```
[MenuID]
[DomainID]
[ParentMenuID]
[Domain_DomainID]
[Domain_DomainID1]
```

So, there is Domain_DomainID and DomainDomainID1 fields are populating mysteriously.

An interesting poing is that; if I remove the Virtual HeaderMenu and Virtual FooterMenu, new fields ([Domain_DomainID], [Domain_DomainID1]) in Menu disappears.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try seeing the database-diagram in SSMS.

Comment: Try setting  [ForeignKey("DomainID")] for the Domain property in the Menu class.

Comment: @jpgrassi I have tried it, it only changed the name of the value to Domain_DomainID but still there is two fields DomainID and Domain_DomainID in Menu table.

Comment: You could generate a script to see where these fields come from. Try Update-Database -Script. Other than that, I would start removing suspect fields and see what the results are. I suspect that the Header and Footer menu properties in the Domain are causing this.

Comment: Yes, you are right @jpgrassi when I remove Header and Footer new fields disappear. But I need them anyway.

Comment: Your modeling seems confusing. You said that A domain may have several menus, and each menu is related to a Domain. That part is fine, but I don't really get why do you use the same Menu entity for Footer and Header. Should't these "parts" be something else? Header and Footer are not "Menus", if you think in a layout way. They are "Containers" that may hold menus.

Comment: I may be wrong and didn't understand your requirements but I would go with another way with this. Domain and Menu are in a One > Many relationship. "domain owners can select where to show to menu" > Shouldn't this be a flag or something? You could use a Enum: 1 - Header 2 - Footer. Got it?

Comment: Yes, you are right @jpgrassi the last soluition will be yours. But I would learn why this occurs.